# Getting the NFC Hardware ID In Android

Tags: android, nfc

I want to do something fairly straightforward, but I can't quite work out if the method in the Gingerbread API is for the ID of the token being scanned or the hardware on-board the Nexus S. What I want to be able to do is get the unique identifier of the NFC chip of the device, so I can register it (eg. when the device is waived over an RFID reader, I can associate the device being waived with an account). Is this possible with the current API methods available?

The piece of code that looks most promising (but I can't test because I don't have a device) is

```
byte[] tagId = intent.getByteArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_ID);
```

Answer (score 8):

tagId is set to an array of bytes. You need to parse that array to a hex string. There's lots of ways to do that, but this code will do it without resorting to external libraries and it's easy to see what's going on:

```
String ByteArrayToHexString(byte [] inarray) 
    {
    int i, j, in;
    String [] hex = {"0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","A","B","C","D","E","F"};
    String out= "";

    for(j = 0 ; j < inarray.length ; ++j) 
        {
        in = (int) inarray[j] & 0xff;
        i = (in >> 4) & 0x0f;
        out += hex[i];
        i = in & 0x0f;
        out += hex[i];
        }
    return out;
}
```

Comment: I have no tag to test, but why don't you use:    byte[] rawTagId = getIntent()
     .getByteArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_ID);
   String tagId = new String(rawTagId);

Answer (score 2):

The intent `NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED` will be automatically dispatched by the NFC controller when a tag is discovered.

1. To handle such intent, you have to add an intent filter for this action `android.nfc.action.TAG_DISCOVERED`:

   ```
   < action android:name="android.nfc.action.TAG_DISCOVERED"/>
   < category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
   ```
2. Add the appropriate permission:

   ```
   < uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
   ```
3. Restrict your application only to supported devices:

   ```
   < uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" />  
   < uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.nfc" />
   ```
4. When you handle the intent, you can call the code you suggested:

   ```
   byte[] tagId = intent.getByteArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_ID);
   NdefMessage[] msgs = (NdefMessage[]) intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES);
   ```

For more information visit:

1. [OpenIntents](http://www.openintents.org/en/node/796)
2. O'Reilly's [online book](http://programming-android.labs.oreilly.com/ch18.html) - Chapter 18

Comment: Although that gets the tag that the device discovers, it doesn't seem to get the details of the on-board NFC hardware. Any way to do that?

Comment: Why not use the device's IMEI or MEID? They are considered unique, and you can register them.

Comment: Because when the device's NFC token is scanned by a reader that info isn't transferred (but that is something that could find its way into Android sooner than getting the device's NFC token)

Answer (score 2):

In version 2.3.3 you have class Tag and if you'll get that object fron intent you can use method getId(),

```
Tag myTag = (Tag) intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
```

and if you need tag id from byte[] as "String" you have to parse it from byte to hex ;).

Comment: I have no tag to test, but why don't you use:    byte[] rawTagId = getIntent()
     .getByteArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_ID);
   String tagId = new String(rawTagId);

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure an "unique identifier of the NFC chip of the device" doesn't exist. There is no obvious reason why anybody could need it.