# Getting the NFC Tag Serial Number

Tags: android, nfc

This is my first project working with NFC. I would like to simply get the ID for the NFC Tag. I have been following the response from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4815718/getting-the-nfc-hardware-id-in-android). Here is the code:

```
public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

    if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(getIntent().getAction())) {

        Toast.makeText(this,"NFC on resume working",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        byte[] tagId = getIntent().getByteArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_ID);
        Log.i("EHEHEHEHEHE",tagId + "");
    }
//process the msgs array
}
```

This is the response of the code:

```
07-06 22:07:29.804  16729-16729/za.co.bookbay.nfcplay I/EHEHEHEHEHE﹕ [B@423a1e18
07-06 22:08:08.644  16729-16729/za.co.bookbay.nfcplay I/EHEHEHEHEHE﹕ [B@423bfde0
07-06 22:08:09.574  16729-16729/za.co.bookbay.nfcplay I/EHEHEHEHEHE﹕ [B@423d6ec8
```

Now this number keeps changing, hence this leads me to believe that the above code is not getting the Tag's serial number or is this correct. If so, what is the reason for the number changing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're printing the byte[] object, not it's content. That's why you get the [B@SomeAddress in your output.

To print the id you can use something like this:

```
String hexdump = new String();
for (int i = 0; i < tagId.length; i++) {
  String x = Integer.toHexString(((int) tagId[i] & 0xff));
  if (x.length() == 1) { 
    x = '0' + x;
  }
  hexdump += x + ' ';
}
Log.i("EHEHEHEHEHE",hexdump);
```

(there is probably a better way to convert a byte-array to a hexdump-string, java is not my favorite programming language)

Answer (score 1):

In Kotlin:

```
var st = ""
val msg = intent.getByteArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_ID)
if (msg != null) {
  st = msg.joinToString(separator = ":"){ eachByte -> "%02x".format(eachByte) }
}
```

will output something like below:

04:53:b0:b0:b3:4b:10

If need upper case, use below instead

for example: 04:53:B0:B0:B3:4B:10

```
"%02X"
```

Comment: I’m also doing my first project with NFC
I got a shorter result, is this correct or not?
"37:c3:81:1c"

Comment: There are many NFC readers to retrieve serial number, you can download from google play and try to verify with them

Comment: Yes, we've already figured it out. Thank you)

Answer (score 0):

You can convert directly ByteArray to HexString with a little function published by [@Roland](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6202869/roland):

```
fun ByteArray.toHexString() = joinToString("") { "%02x".format(it) }
```

Next link can you help more:
[Converting a byte array into a hex string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52225212/converting-a-byte-array-into-a-hex-string)