# Converting a byte array into a hex string

Tags: arrays, string, kotlin, hex, byte

Surprisingly (to me), this code does not do what I want:

```
fun ByteArray.toHexString() : String {
    return this.joinToString("") { it.toString(16) }
}
```

Turns out `Byte` is *signed*, so you get negative hex representations for individual bytes, which leads to a completely bogus end result.

Also, `Byte.toString` won't pad leading zeroes, which you'd want here.

What is the simplest (no additional libraries, ideally no extensions) resp. most efficient fix?

Comment: ... can you give me an input for which you get the bogus output?

Comment: @Roland `0xFF.toByte().toString(16)`

Comment: @Roland My hint was seeing `-` in SHA-256 hashes.

Comment: tried all single byte strings from `0x00` upto `0xFF`. All variants on this page produce the same result.. what am I missing here?

Comment: just wondering: how do you get your `ByteArray`?

Comment: @Roland Converted UTF-8 strings to `ByteArray`, put that one through hashing and encryption (separately) using BouncyCastle. Can't reproduce [without crypto elements](https://pastebin.com/4X1R3TKg), huh.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

As I am on Kotlin 1.3 you may also be interested in the `UByte` soon (note that it's an experimental feature. See also [Kotlin 1.3M1](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2018/07/see-whats-coming-in-kotlin-1-3-m1/) and [1.3M2 announcement](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2018/08/kotlin-1-3-m2/))

E.g.:

```
@ExperimentalUnsignedTypes // just to make it clear that the experimental unsigned types are used
fun ByteArray.toHexString() = asUByteArray().joinToString("") { it.toString(16).padStart(2, '0') }
```

The formatting option is probably the nicest other variant (but maybe not that easily readable... and I always forget how it works, so it is definitely not so easy to remember (for me :-)):

```
fun ByteArray.toHexString() = joinToString("") { "%02x".format(it) }
```

Comment: In case somebody needs a version that does not target JVM: ```fun ByteArray.toHexString() = joinToString("") { (0xFF and it.toInt()).toString(16).padStart(2, '0') }```

Answer (score 10):

`printf` does what we want here:

```
fun ByteArray.toHexString() : String {
    return this.joinToString("") {
        java.lang.String.format("%02x", it)
    }
}
```

Comment: I doubt that you need to spell out `java.lang.String`

Comment: @msrd0 There is no Java tag on the question. Using KotlinJS I can appreciate when I can rule out an answer like that at the first glance.

Comment: @msrd0 I think I wanted to make sure not to pick Kotlin's `String`, but it does indeed seem to be unnecessary.

Comment: @Zackline Interesting point. Has any convention for tagging Kotlin questions regarding JVM/JS/Android/Native emerged yet?

Answer (score 5):

In case someone searches and finds this question in the future, here is an answer for Kotlin 1.9+.

There is a new experimental feature, [`fun ByteArray.toHexString(format: HexFormat = HexFormat.Default)`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/to-hex-string.html)

To use it very simply:

```
byteArrayOf(0x0A, 0x0B, 0x0C).toHexString() returns "0x0b0c"
```

You can customize it:

```
val hexFormat = HexFormat { bytes { byteSeparator = " "; upperCase = true } }
byteArrayOf(0x0A, 0x0B, 0x0C).toHexString(hexFormat) returns "0A 0B 0C"
```

Answer (score 3):

This question has been answered, but I did not like the formatting.  Here is something that formats it into something more readable ... at least for me.

```
@JvmOverloads
fun ByteArray.toHexString(separator: CharSequence = " ",  prefix: CharSequence = "[",  postfix: CharSequence = "]") =
    this.joinToString(separator, prefix, postfix) {
        String.format("0x%02X", it)
    }
```

output:

```
[0x10 0x22]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
fun ByteArray.toHexString() = joinToString("") {
    Integer.toUnsignedString(java.lang.Byte.toUnsignedInt(it), 16).padStart(2, '0')
}
```

Fortunately, Java has `toUnsignedString` methods on `Integer` and `Long`. UNfortunately, these methods are *only* on `Integer` and `Long`, so you need to convert each byte first (using [`Byte#toUnsignedInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Byte.html#toUnsignedInt(byte))).

Comment: Any reason for the downvote? While there are better methods now available that are built-in to Kotlin, this is still correct and efficient (for Kotlin/JVM).

Comment: @Hett I'm not sure what you mean, it certainly does work correctly ([example](https://tio.run/##VU8xDsIwDNz7CqtLE6mKUgY2BhgqmBiABwQRopTiVMGgVoi3hwS1CDxYOvt8d744ai2GcL4jrAbSS@/VIMitdb8jb9EwDgtonMW9Gwd5zuGZQawNkjbaR/oBb9agPo2URj2UaBUakTR/9vGCWeIlVHMuOhX5yhOblVDIgmevLEs5rsoimzy6KEgtsuMUbntmspdVCbKvZOq1jAbJh/EPrL@Q/z8SDUJ4Aw)) and does not produce the behavior described in the question? There aren't any incorrect `-`s anywhere in the output and the individual bytes are padded properly.