Getting different SHA-224 values in Python and Kotlin Android
Need to validate the Hash value for a Json response received from the backend. The hash value is properly calculated in Python and matched with backend server hash value which is correct. where as I am getting a different hash value always in the Kotlin Android. sharing the code snippets below.
Python:
import json
import hashlib
import base64

msg = {
    "name": "Alice",
    "age": 25,
    "address": {
        "city": "Wonderland",
        "street": "Rabbit Hole"
    }
}

# Sort keys and ensure ASCII encoding
json_str = json.dumps(msg, ensure_ascii=False, sort_keys=True)
print(f"Serialized JSON (Python): {json_str}")

json_bin = json_str.encode('utf-8')

# Create SHA-224 hash and take first 16 bytes
hash_calculator = hashlib.sha224(json_bin)
hash_digest = hash_calculator.digest()[:16]

# Print hex digest
print(f"Hex digest (Python): {hash_digest.hex()}")

# Base64 encode
hash_encoded64 = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(hash_digest).decode('utf8')
print(f"Base64 encoded hash (Python): {hash_encoded64}")

But when I convert the same python code to Kotlin and run, I am getting different value. Could anyone check this and let me know what is going wrong?
Kotlin:
    fun calculateHas(){
        // Original JSON message as a string
        val msg = """
        {
    "name": "Alice",
    "age": 25,
    "address": {
        "city": "Wonderland",
        "street": "Rabbit Hole"
      }
    }
        """.trim().trimIndent().replace("\n","")

        // Parse the JSON string into a JSONObject
        val jsonObj = JSONObject(msg)

        // Serialize the JSONObject into a string with sorted keys
        val sortedJsonObj = JSONObject()
        val keys = jsonObj.keys().asSequence().toList().sorted()
        for (key in keys) {
            sortedJsonObj.put(key, jsonObj.get(key))
        }
        val sortedJsonStr = sortedJsonObj.toString().replace("\n","").toByteArray(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)

        // Create a SHA-224 hash of the JSON byte array
        val sha224Digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-224")
        val hashBytes = sha224Digest.digest(sortedJsonStr)

        // Get the first 16 bytes of the hash
        val truncatedHash = hashBytes.sliceArray(0 until 16)

        // Encode the truncated hash in Base64 (URL-safe, without padding)
        val hashBase64 = Base64.encodeToString(truncatedHash, Base64.URL_SAFE or Base64.NO_WRAP)

        // Print the Base64-encoded hash
        println(hashBase64)
        Log.e("Code:" , hashBase64)
    }


(1) Did you check that the serialized strings are identical? (2) Did you compare hex values too?

You are trying to make a sorted JSONObject which "is an unordered collection".

@Jan Itor - That is my requirement. even though the order of the json keys changed, the hash should not changed. Also the Python code is doing same.

@dev.bmax
I did not checked hex values. could you please help me in that.

See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52225212/converting-a-byte-array-into-a-hex-string

You don't have to look at the hex values to see that the strings in Kotlin and Python are different. One has spaces, the other hasn't.

You are taking a hash of a JSON string. The representation of JSON objects as strings is not standardized, and by doing this you are exposing yourself to a lot of risk. As it happens, your JSON strings produced by Python and Kotlin are different:
Produced by Python using json.dumps:
{"address": {"city": "Wonderland", "street": "Rabbit Hole"}, "age": 25, "name": "Alice"}

Produced by Kotlin using JSONObject.toString:
{"address":{"city":"Wonderland","street":"Rabbit Hole"},"name":"Alice","age":25}

I assume you are using org.json.JSONObject from the JSON-Java library (it would have helped if you specified it). That library creates a string with no spacing. You need a way to create a JSON string that matches the one produced by Python. It would be wrong to add a space after colons and commas manually, because that might also alter the data, which you don't want to change. Instead, you need to find a way to change the separators used. I don't think the JSON-Java library has a way to do that, but you can do it with Gson:
val gson = GsonBuilder()
    .setFormattingStyle(FormattingStyle.COMPACT.withSpaceAfterSeparators(true))
    .create()
...
val sortedJsonStr = gson.toJson(sortedJsonObj)
val sortedJsonBytes = sortedJsonStr.toByteArray(UTF_8)

or with Jackson:
val objectMapper = ObjectMapper()
val objectWriter = objectMapper.writer(
    DefaultPrettyPrinter()
        .withObjectIndenter(DefaultPrettyPrinter.NopIndenter.instance)
        .withArrayIndenter(DefaultPrettyPrinter.NopIndenter.instance)
        .withSeparators(
            PrettyPrinter.DEFAULT_SEPARATORS
                .withObjectFieldValueSpacing(Separators.Spacing.AFTER)
                .withObjectEntrySpacing(Separators.Spacing.AFTER)
        )
)
...
val sortedJsonStr = objectWriter.writeValueAsString(sortedJsonObj)
val sortedJsonBytes = sortedJsonStr.toByteArray(UTF_8)

Another way is to change Python's output to match Kotlin's. You can do this by specifying separators with no spaces:
json.dumps(msg, ensure_ascii=False, sort_keys=True, separators=(',',':'))

Of course, that would mean that you would have to re-hash any existing hashes on your server so that they don't use spaces.
Now, if you are lucky, you might have a JSON string that is the same whether it's produced by Kotlin or Python code. If you are lucky. We've just made the spacing the same, but there may be other things that are different, such as date and time formats, or how unprintable Unicode/control characters are represented. So my advice would be to not use JSON strings for calculating a hash, but find a different mechanism which is reproducible.
