# NFC Serial Number (UID) to String

Tags: android, nfc

I am creating an app that I want to read the NFC Serial Number, Store it (maybe in a shared preference) and then use the SN to trigger an action if it is true.

I have uploaded my project to GitHub in hopes it better explains what I am trying to do.
https://github.com/soboapps/PunchCard

I found some code that reads the NFC tag and it's working great. I have integrated it into my app, but my struggle is trying to Extract the individual pieces of the tag.

Could someone please tell me how to get what I believe is in

```
resolveIntent(Intent intent)
    byte[] id = intent.getByteArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_ID);
```

But I just can't figure out how to convert it to a String so I can store it.

Here is the entire Class.  There are other classes that came with this code, but I think what I need is in here somewhere.

```
package com.soboapps.compare;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.nfc.NdefMessage;
import android.nfc.NdefRecord;
import android.nfc.NfcAdapter;
import android.nfc.Tag;
import android.nfc.tech.MifareClassic;
import android.nfc.tech.MifareUltralight;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import com.soboapps.compare.record.ParsedNdefRecord;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
        NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    public static final String TAG = "NfcDemo";

    //Declaration
    private static final String NAV_ITEM_ID = "navItemId" ;
    private static final long DRAWER_CLOSE_DELAY_MS = 300 ;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private int mNavItemId;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    private final CofFragment mCofFragment= new CofFragment();
    private final SandFragment mSandFragment = new SandFragment();
    private final Handler mDrawerActionHandler = new Handler();

    private static final DateFormat TIME_FORMAT = SimpleDateFormat.getDateTimeInstance();
    private LinearLayout mTagContent;

    private NfcAdapter mAdapter;
    private PendingIntent mPendingIntent;
    private NdefMessage mNdefPushMessage;

    private AlertDialog mDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Initialize Drawer layout -> activity_main
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        //Initialize Toolbar android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        Toolbar mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);

        //Load saved navigation state if present
        if (null==savedInstanceState){
            mNavItemId = R.id.drawer_item_1;
        }else{
            mNavItemId = savedInstanceState.getInt(NAV_ITEM_ID);
        }

        // Listen to navigation events
        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        //Select the Correct nav menu item
        navigationView.getMenu().findItem(mNavItemId).setChecked(true);

        // Setup the humberger icon to open and close drawer
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, mToolbar, R.string.open, R.string.close);
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();

        // navigate function to swich between items id
        // parameter item id
        navigate(mNavItemId);

        mTagContent = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.list);
        resolveIntent(getIntent());

        mDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setNeutralButton("Ok", null).create();

        mAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
        if (mAdapter == null) {
            showMessage(R.string.error, R.string.no_nfc);
            finish();
            return;
        }

        mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                new Intent(this, getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), 0);
        mNdefPushMessage = new NdefMessage(new NdefRecord[] { newTextRecord(
                "Message from NFC Reader :-)", Locale.ENGLISH, true) });


    }

    private void navigate(final int itemId) {
        switch (itemId){
            case R.id.drawer_item_1:
                //start about fragment
                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content,mCofFragment).commit();
                break;
            case R.id.drawer_item_2:
                //start project fragment
                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content, mSandFragment).commit();
                break;
        }
    }


    private void showMessage(int title, int message) {
        mDialog.setTitle(title);
        mDialog.setMessage(getText(message));
        mDialog.show();
    }

    private NdefRecord newTextRecord(String text, Locale locale, boolean encodeInUtf8) {
        byte[] langBytes = locale.getLanguage().getBytes(Charset.forName("US-ASCII"));

        Charset utfEncoding = encodeInUtf8 ? Charset.forName("UTF-8") : Charset.forName("UTF-16");
        byte[] textBytes = text.getBytes(utfEncoding);

        int utfBit = encodeInUtf8 ? 0 : (1 << 7);
        char status = (char) (utfBit + langBytes.length);

        byte[] data = new byte[1 + langBytes.length + textBytes.length];
        data[0] = (byte) status;
        System.arraycopy(langBytes, 0, data, 1, langBytes.length);
        System.arraycopy(textBytes, 0, data, 1 + langBytes.length, textBytes.length);

        return new NdefRecord(NdefRecord.TNF_WELL_KNOWN, NdefRecord.RTD_TEXT, new byte[0], data);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (mAdapter != null) {
            if (!mAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                showWirelessSettingsDialog();
            }
            mAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, mPendingIntent, null, null);
            mAdapter.enableForegroundNdefPush(this, mNdefPushMessage);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (mAdapter != null) {
            mAdapter.disableForegroundDispatch(this);
            mAdapter.disableForegroundNdefPush(this);
        }
    }

    private void showWirelessSettingsDialog() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage(R.string.nfc_disabled);
        builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                finish();
            }
        });
        builder.create().show();
        return;
    }

    private void resolveIntent(Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.equals(action)
                || NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED.equals(action)
                || NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(action)) {
            Parcelable[] rawMsgs = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES);
            NdefMessage[] msgs;
            if (rawMsgs != null) {
                msgs = new NdefMessage[rawMsgs.length];
                for (int i = 0; i < rawMsgs.length; i++) {
                    msgs[i] = (NdefMessage) rawMsgs[i];
                }
            } else {
                // Unknown tag type
                byte[] empty = new byte[0];
                byte[] id = intent.getByteArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_ID);

                Parcelable tag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);


                byte[] payload = dumpTagData(tag).getBytes();
                NdefRecord record = new NdefRecord(NdefRecord.TNF_UNKNOWN, empty, id, payload);
                NdefMessage msg = new NdefMessage(new NdefRecord[] { record });
                msgs = new NdefMessage[] { msg  } ;



            }
            // Setup the views

            buildTagViews(msgs);


        }



        //To display the UID

    }



    private String dumpTagData(Parcelable p) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        Tag tag = (Tag) p;
        byte[] id = tag.getId();
        sb.append("Tag ID (hex): ").append(getHex(id)).append("\n");
        sb.append("Tag ID (dec): ").append(getDec(id)).append("\n");
        sb.append("ID (reversed): ").append(getReversed(id)).append("\n");

        String prefix = "android.nfc.tech.";
        sb.append("Technologies: ");
        for (String tech : tag.getTechList()) {
            sb.append(tech.substring(prefix.length()));
            sb.append(", ");
        }
        sb.delete(sb.length() - 2, sb.length());
        for (String tech : tag.getTechList()) {
            if (tech.equals(MifareClassic.class.getName())) {
                sb.append('\n');
                MifareClassic mifareTag = MifareClassic.get(tag);
                String type = "Unknown";
                switch (mifareTag.getType()) {
                    case MifareClassic.TYPE_CLASSIC:
                        type = "Classic";
                        break;
                    case MifareClassic.TYPE_PLUS:
                        type = "Plus";
                        break;
                    case MifareClassic.TYPE_PRO:
                        type = "Pro";
                        break;
                }
                sb.append("Mifare Classic type: ");
                sb.append(type);
                sb.append('\n');

                sb.append("Mifare size: ");
                sb.append(mifareTag.getSize() + " bytes");
                sb.append('\n');

                sb.append("Mifare sectors: ");
                sb.append(mifareTag.getSectorCount());
                sb.append('\n');

                sb.append("Mifare blocks: ");
                sb.append(mifareTag.getBlockCount());
            }

            if (tech.equals(MifareUltralight.class.getName())) {
                sb.append('\n');
                MifareUltralight mifareUlTag = MifareUltralight.get(tag);
                String type = "Unknown";
                switch (mifareUlTag.getType()) {
                    case MifareUltralight.TYPE_ULTRALIGHT:
                        type = "Ultralight";
                        break;
                    case MifareUltralight.TYPE_ULTRALIGHT_C:
                        type = "Ultralight C";
                        break;
                }
                sb.append("Mifare Ultralight type: ");
                sb.append(type);
            }
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }

    private String getHex(byte[] bytes) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = bytes.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
            int b = bytes[i] & 0xff;
            if (b < 0x10)
                sb.append('0');
            sb.append(Integer.toHexString(b));
            if (i > 0) {
                sb.append(" ");
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();

    }

    private long getDec(byte[] bytes) {
        long result = 0;
        long factor = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; ++i) {
            long value = bytes[i] & 0xffl;
            result += value * factor;
            factor *= 256l;
        }
        return result;
    }

    private long getReversed(byte[] bytes) {
        long result = 0;
        long factor = 1;
        for (int i = bytes.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
            long value = bytes[i] & 0xffl;
            result += value * factor;
            factor *= 256l;
        }
        return result;
    }

    void buildTagViews(NdefMessage[] msgs) {
        if (msgs == null || msgs.length == 0) {
            return;
        }
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        LinearLayout content = mTagContent;

        // Parse the first message in the list
        // Build views for all of the sub records
        Date now = new Date();
        List<ParsedNdefRecord> records = NdefMessageParser.parse(msgs[0]);
        final int size = records.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            TextView timeView = new TextView(this);
            timeView.setText(TIME_FORMAT.format(now));
            content.addView(timeView, 0);
            ParsedNdefRecord record = records.get(i);

            content.addView(record.getView(this, inflater, content, i), 1 + i);
            content.addView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.tag_divider, content, false), 2 + i);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(final Configuration newConfig){
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed(){
        if(mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)){
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        }else{
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(final Bundle outState){
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt(NAV_ITEM_ID, mNavItemId);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        final int id = item.getItemId();

        if(id== android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.home){
            return mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * -Handles clicks on the navigation menu
     * @param menuItem
     * @return
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(final MenuItem menuItem) {
        //Update highlighted item in the navigation menu
        menuItem.setChecked(true);
        mNavItemId = menuItem.getItemId();

        // Time gap after closing the navigation to see animation
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        mDrawerActionHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                navigate(menuItem.getItemId());
            }
        }, DRAWER_CLOSE_DELAY_MS);
        return true;
    }



    @Override
    public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        setIntent(intent);
        resolveIntent(intent);
    }
}
```

EDIT:
I added what I think is suggested.  IO am getting an error in "context" now, but really I just want to know if this is what is being suggested?

```
private String getHex(byte[] bytes) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = bytes.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
        int b = bytes[i] & 0xff;
        if (b < 0x10)
            sb.append('0');
        sb.append(Integer.toHexString(b));
        if (i > 0) {
            sb.append(" ");
        }
    }

    return sb.toString();

    final SharedPreferences prefs =  context.getSharedPreferences("CHECK_POINT_NAME",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putString("CHECK_POINT", String.valueOf(sb));
    editor.apply();

}
```

Comment: What do you want to do with it after you store it?  Are you expecting to be formatted a certain way?

Comment: So when I scan the Tag I can verify it's the same tag and then "register" that scan.  A "check-in" basically.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to convert `byte[]` to `String` just write

```
String s = new String(id);
```

**EDIT**
from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5654919/3763848)

```
String ByteArrayToHexString(byte [] inarray) 
    {
    int i, j, in;
    String [] hex = {"0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","A","B","C","D","E","F"};
    String out= "";

    for(j = 0 ; j < inarray.length ; ++j) 
        {
        in = (int) inarray[j] & 0xff;
        i = (in >> 4) & 0x0f;
        out += hex[i];
        i = in & 0x0f;
        out += hex[i];
        }
    return out;
}
```

Comment: This won't work because it's expecting that the byte array is a series of bytes described by the system's default character set. NFC IDs are not sequences of characters that can be converted like this.

Comment: so he wants one by one the bytes?

Comment: I added  String s = new String(id);   and then this toast...  Toast t = Toast.makeText(this.getApplicationContext(), s, Toastst.LENGTH_SHORT);  t.setGravity(Gravity.TOP | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0, 0); t.show();  But it did not show anything

Answer (score 1):

You actually have a method right there in your code that converts byte arrays to hex strings.  It's called getHex().  You can pass the NFC ID byte array to it to get a hex string that you can store and compare to other IDs to see if it matches another serial number.

Comment: I edited my question to include the getHex() with what I "think" you are suggesting.  Can you please confirm.  Thanks

Comment: I guess my question is How do I use that method to store that number as a SharedPreference?

Comment: You're getting a String from getHex(), so you just store it as you would any other String and compare it as you would any other String.

Comment: Thank you.  I figured out what you were saying.  I added the String sNum and used sNum = new String(getHex(id)); to get the Serial Number as a String.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I found the better answer for my project.  I added nfcTagSerialNum as a public static String and then I added the following to my resolveIntent(Internet intent)

```
Tag tagFromIntent = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
byte[] extraID = tagFromIntent.getId();

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (byte b : extraID) {
    sb.append(String.format("%02X", b));
};

nfcTagSerialNum = sb.toString();
Log.e("nfc ID", nfcTagSerialNum);
```

I was then able to use the String "nfcTagSerialNum" wherever I wanted.